# MongoDB find the last high

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to get the closest price which is higher than the latest price. The example (MongoDB) is showed below.

The latest date is '2021/01/05' in example.

For 'id 0001', the closest price which is higher than the latest price is 30, and the latest price is 20.
For 'id 0002', no price is higher than the latest price so the closest price is the latest price(140).

db.stock.find()

//result

```
[

    {'id':'0001','date':'2021/01/01','price':50}
    {'id':'0001','date':'2021/01/02','price':40}
    {'id':'0001','date':'2021/01/03','price':30}
    {'id':'0001','date':'2021/01/04','price':10}
    {'id':'0001','date':'2021/01/05','price':20}
    {'id':'0002','date':'2021/01/01','price':100}
    {'id':'0002','date':'2021/01/02','price':110}
    {'id':'0002','date':'2021/01/03','price':120}
    {'id':'0002','date':'2021/01/04','price':130}
    {'id':'0002','date':'2021/01/05','price':140}
    ...
]
```

Expected output showed below.

the closest price is 20 higher than 10 but it is less than 30(the closest price is higher than one price), so 'days' is 1 in case '0001'.

the closest price is 140 higher than 130,120,110,100 (the closest price is higher than four price), so 'days' is 4 in case '0002'.

```
 [   
        {'id':'0001', 'latest_date':'2021/01/05',
'the_closest_date':'2021/01/03',
'the_closest_price':30, 
'days':1},
        {'id':'0002', 'latest_date':'2021/01/05',
'the_closest_date':'2021/01/05',
'the_closest_price':140, 
'days':4}
    ]
```

Comment: Your condition is not consistent. 140 is not higher than latest price 140 (it is equal). If your condition shall be "closest price which is higher or equal than the latest price" then for `id: "0001"` the result would be also 20 (not 30).

Comment: The price must be numbers, not strings. Otherwise price `"9"` would be higher than `"100"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the bellow does what you need.
sorts by date,then groups,and then finds the member with the first bigger price, if it finds saves the date.

[Run code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kQc_6SW3aSZ)

```json
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "g": {
        "$push": {
          "price": "$price",
          "date": "$date"
        }
      },
      "latest-date": {
        "$max": "$date"
      },
      "price": {
        "$first": "$price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "days-date-found": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$g",
          "initialValue": [
            -1,
            -1,
            false
          ],
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "days_date_found": "$$value",
                "m": "$$this"
              },
              "in": {
                "$let": {
                  "vars": {
                    "days": {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$$days_date_found",
                        0
                      ]
                    },
                    "date": {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$$days_date_found",
                        1
                      ]
                    },
                    "found": {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$$days_date_found",
                        2
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "in": {
                    "$switch": {
                      "branches": [
                        {
                          "case": "$$found",
                          "then": "$$days_date_found"
                        },
                        {
                          "case": {
                            "$gt": [
                              "$$m.price",
                              "$price"
                            ]
                          },
                          "then": [
                            "$$days",
                            "$$m.date",
                            true
                          ]
                        }
                      ],
                      "default": [
                        {
                          "$add": [
                            "$$days",
                            1
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$m.date",
                        false
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "days": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$days-date-found",
          0
        ]
      },
      "closest-date": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$days-date-found",
              2
            ]
          },
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$days-date-found",
              1
            ]
          },
          "$latest-date"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "days-date-found",
      "g"
    ]
  }
])
```

If it doesn't if you can give some more data, and how they should be after the query.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my commend your requirement is not consistent. Also you don't explain how to determine field `days`.

This is my solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { date: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      data: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      latest_price: { $last: "$price" },
      latest_date: { $last: "$date" }
    }
  },
  {   // Remove this stage if the latest price/date can be the result. However, then it will be **always** the latest one
    $set: { 
      data: {
        $slice: [ "$data",  0, { $subtract: [ { $size: "$data" }, 1 ] } ]
      }
    }
  },  
  {  // Filter days where price > latest price
    $set: {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: { $gt: [ "$$this.price", "$latest_price" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // Calculate difference between price and latest price
    $set: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                diff: {
                  $subtract: [
                    "$$this.price",
                    "$latest_price"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // Filter by minimum difference (note, there might be more than just one)
    $set: {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.diff", { $min: "$data.diff" } ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // Compose final output 
    $project: {
      latest_date: 1,
      the_closest_date: { $first: "$data.date" },
      the_closest_price: { $first: "$data.price" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/THp28Wot1lY)